# Mocha + Chai não acessam rotas que precisam de autenticação

Tags: node.js, testes-de-unidade, back-end, jwt, mocha

Fala galera, boa tarde.

Então, estou fazendo alguns testes na minha API em Node.js usando Mocha e chai, porém eu tenho um middleware que verifica o token do meu usuário para que ele possa ter acesso a algumas requisicoes HTTP.

O teste de login funciona corretamente, porém quando tenho fazer testes com as rotas protegidas pelo middleware não da certo.

```js
process.env.ESTACAO_HACK_ALUNOS_DATABASE_MODE = "test"; 
process.env.ESTACAO_HACK_ALUNOS_DATABASE_HOST = "localhost";

const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Student = require('../models/student');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

const app = require('../server.js');

let activeStudent = new Student({
    name: "Active Student",
    email: "active@mastertech.tech",
    cpf: "192.834.586-11",
    picture: "public/images/gas.jpg-1532709990908",
    resume: "public/docs/docteste.pdf-1532709991846",
    description: "Descrição básica",
    group: "Turma 1",
    isWorking: false,
    birthDate: "01/09/1998",
    active: true
});

let inactiveStudent = new Student({
    name: "Inactive Student",
    email: "inactive@mastertech.tech",
    cpf: "012.345.678-99",
    picture: "public/images/ney.jpg-1532709990908",
    resume: "public/docs/DOCUMENTO TESTE PDF.pdf-1532709991846",
    description: "Descrição básica",
    group: "Turma 1",
    isWorking: false,
    birthDate: "01/09/1998"
});

before((done) => {
    mongoose.connection.collections.students.drop(() => {
        console.log("[Admin Test START] Cleared 'students' collection");
        activeStudent.save()
        .then((activeStudent) => {
            activeStudent = activeStudent;
            inactiveStudent.save()
            .then((inactiveStudent) => {
                console.log("[Admin Test START] Students added");
                inactiveStudent = inactiveStudent;
                done();
            })
        })
    });
});

describe('Admin', () => {
    describe('Get Students', () => {
        it('All', (done) => {
            chai.request(app)
            .get('/students')
            .then(response => {
                expect(response).to.have.status(200);
                expect(response.body).to.be.an('array');
                expect(response.headers.authorization);
                expect(response.body.length).to.be.equal(2);
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return err;
            });       
        });
        
        it('Inactive', (done) => {
            chai.request(app)
            .get('/students/inactive')
            .then(response => {
                expect(response).to.have.status(200);
                expect(response.body).to.be.an('array');
                expect(response.body.length).to.be.equal(1);
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return err;
            });       
        });
        
        it('Active', (done) => {
            chai.request(app)
            .get('/students/active')
            .then(response => {
                expect(response).to.have.status(200);
                expect(response.body).to.be.an('array');
                expect(response.body.length).to.be.equal(1);
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return err;
            });       
        });
      });
    });
```

Nesse teste, teria que me retornar os students porém quando executo o teste recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> 1) Admin
>          Get Students
>            All:
>        Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/raphaelmelo/Área de Trabalho/estacao-hack-alunos-api/test/adminTests.js)
>
> 2) Admin
>          Get Students
>            Inactive:
>        Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/raphaelmelo/Área de Trabalho/estacao-hack-alunos-api/test/adminTests.js)
>
> 3) Admin
>          Get Students
>            Active:
>        Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/raphaelmelo/Área de Trabalho/estacao-hack-alunos-api/test/adminTests.js).

todos os outros teste que não dependem do token passam normalmente.

Já entendi que preciso setar o token nesses testes, porém não estou conseguindo entender a sintaxe disso, será que alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Como está o código do seu middleware? E  aonde você está passando a autenticação?

Answer (score 0):

Aumente o timeout de execução do mocha. No meu caso meu comando `yarn test` possui a flag `--timeout` do mocha.

`./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout 10000 --exit test`